# Walletconnect suddenly stopped working, infinite loading

Tags: wallet-connect, web3modal, wagmi

I've a website that has been deployed for weeks and it was working fine, I didn't even touch the code and it's now not working. Even on the WalletConnect website, their "connect wallet" buttons are not working.

But I've Checked other websites, and some of them are working. so is it an issue in v2 only, or is it something else?

There's an error in the console

```
Uncaught Error: ClientCtrl has no client set
    at Object.client (index.es-03be019a.js:1:305)
    at Object.getSelectedChain (index.es-03be019a.js:1:4084)
    at new vt (index.es-03be019a.js:1:101964)
    at fe.u (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:2936)
    at W.g (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:4569)
    at W._$AI (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:4054)
    at fe.v (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:3383)
    at W.g (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:4587)
    at W._$AI (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:4054)
    at ge (animate.es-3013c75e.js:15:7352)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dependencies mismatch.

I fixed it by deleting `node_modules` and switching back from yarn to npm (and forcing a bit).